# Correct way to handle menus

Tags: android, android-fragments, appcompatactivity

In my application I have one Activity: MainActivity that extends AppCompatActivity.

Now I have three fragments: NewHome, Settings, BatchDelete.

On run I replace my FrameLayout with NewHome:

```java
if (savedInstanceState == null && !mDir.equals("")) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_layout, new NewHome(), NewHome.class.getSimpleName())
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .commit();
        }
```

I have added a back callback:

```java
getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                mHideMenu = false;
                Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                MainActivity.super.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
```

In this MainActivity I create my meny with four items: Search, Filter, Batch Delete and Settings.
Search and Filter is handled in NewHome Fragment, so when user click on search, it shows a searchview and handle filter() in fragment, and when filter is clicked it shows a layout in the fragment.

When user click on Batch Delete or Settings I handle those click in menu:

```java
int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == android.R.id.home) {
            super.getOnBackPressedDispatcher().onBackPressed();
            Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0 ) mHideMenu = false;
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            return true;
        } else 
            BatchDelete batchDelete = (BatchDelete) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(BatchDelete.class.getSimpleName());
            if (batchDelete == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_layout, new BatchDelete())
                        .addToBackStack(BatchDelete.class.getSimpleName())
                        .setTransition(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                        .commit();
                mHideMenu = true;
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            }
        } else if (itemId == R.id.menu_settings) {
            Settings settings = (Settings) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Settings.class.getSimpleName());
            if (settings == null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_layout, new Settings())
                        .addToBackStack(Settings.class.getSimpleName())
                        .setTransition(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                        .commit();
                Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                mHideMenu = true;
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }
```

and this is my onPrepareOptionsMenu:

```java
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (mHideMenu) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.batch_delete).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_filter).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_settings).setVisible(false);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.batch_delete).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_filter).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_settings).setVisible(true);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

So I have this behavior: When click on Settings it shows Settings Fragment, and show Home (back) in Toolbar and hides other menu items.
When user click home (`android.R.id.home`), it correctly `popBackStackImmediate()` and Menu is correcly updated.
But when I go back (system gesture or navbar), it correctly `popBackStackImmediate()` but Menu is not updated.

So the questions are:

1. Is this the correct way to handle menus?
2. Should I use menu in each Fragment instead of MainAtivity?
3. Why onPrepareOptionsMenu is not called in backPressed() ?

Thank you everyone.

backPressed() not updates the menu